# How do I get a value from another sheet, a specific row and column based on dropdown value with a range?

Tags: google-sheets

I've created a LANGUAGE sheet with each word in a row and its translation in the next row. I can now add new languages as needed by adding columns with translations.

I've then set up a language dropdown menu containing all languages (=LANGUAGES!$1:$1) automatically.

Now, HOW do I put the value in a cell based on the dropdown?

Say I have the word 'Faktura' in the first column (second row) under the language 'DA' (first row) and the word 'Invoice' in the next column under 'EN'.

Put this word in the cell if the Dropdown has DA selected otherwise put this word in the cell if the Dropdown has EN selected.

Hope this makes sense. I'm pretty sure it's simple, but I can't wrap my head around how to make Google Sheet do what I want it to.

I've been wildly guessing with things like: =LANGUAGES!$1:1???????=F3<-DataValidationField) ... simply cannot figure out or even guess what to write in the formular. Mind bendingly counter intuitive.

Comment: Hey, is it possible to have a dummy sheet with expected values ?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Use: =HLOOKUP(F3;LANGUAGES!A:B;2;false)

Where F3 is the cell for the dropdown (the range) A:B represents the col range and 2 the row to get the word from ...